# Line-to-line intersect with pygame's inverted y-axis

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line%E2%80%93line_intersection#Given_two_points_on_each_line

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TOEi6T2mtHo

I have tried to implement this method in my code but to no avail, I do believe the issue is the inverted y-axis in pygame or is something else hiding under my sight? Any suggestions?

Here's my code:

```
        x1 = other.pos1[0]
        y1 = other.pos1[1]
        x2 = other.pos2[0]
        y2 = other.pos2[1]

        x3 = self.pos1[0]
        y3 = self.pos1[1]
        x4 = self.pos2[0]
        y4 = self.pos2[1]

        den = (x1 - x2) * (y3 - y4) - (y1 * y2 * (x3 - x4))

        if den == 0:
            return

        t = ((x1 - x3) * (y3 - y4) - (y1 - y3) * (x3 - x4)) / den

        u = -(((x1 - x2) * (y1 - y3) - (y1 - y2) * (x1 - x3))) / den

        if t > 0 and t < 1 and u > 0:
            point = (x3 + u * (x4 - x3), y3 + u * (y4 - y3))

            pygame.gfxdraw.filled_circle(surface, point[0], point[1], 3, (255, 0, 0))

            return point

        else:
            return
```

Comment: `(x1 - x2) * (y3 - y4) - (y1 * y2 * (x3 - x4))` has to be `(x1-x2)*(y3-y4) - (y1-y2)*(x3-x4))`

Comment: Oh my good god, thank you so much, I feel dumb now

Comment: Heads up. Bugs like this have happened to all of us.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The denominator for the [Line–line intersection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant) is calculated by the formula:

> ```
> (x1 - x2) * (y3 - y4) - (y1 - y2) * (x3 - x4).
> ```

So the following expression is wrong:

> ```
> den = (x1 - x2) * (y3 - y4) - (y1 * y2 * (x3 - x4))
> ```

It has to be:

```py
den = (x1-x2)*(y3-y4) - (y1-y2)*(x3-x4))
```